# I want to transfer a question back to Stackoverflow after being put on hold.

Tags: support, migration

I had asked a [Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903473/flashtool-only-gives-a-list-of-sony-phones-android?noredirect=1#comment31377417_20903473) at Stackoverflow, but the question was put on hold citing the **User** perspective of the nature of Question. It was not considered fit for Stackoverflow because there was not much Developer context in the question. I was directed to post this question on SuperUser(Which I promptly did after deleting the said question).

However after some days the [Question](https://superuser.com/questions/696558/wrong-oem-while-trying-to-use-flashtool-android-rooting?noredirect=1#comment886502_696558) on SuperUser has become more detailed and I think its a pure development question now. I want to know can I transfer this question back to Stackoverflow, to get a more detailed answer, plus more response.

Comment: Ok, I threw you a reopen vote and an upvote based on the fact that you said you would edit it to be appropriate.  Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you, I have done so :)

Comment: I still don't really see how this is a programming issue though. Just because it references Java?

Comment: Feels more like it's general purpose software rather than anything specifically dealing with code.  The question on Super User is fine; the one on Stack Overflow is still off-topic.

Comment: Though the JVM error makes me think otherwise, I might be wrong..

Comment: And why a minus vote here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm thinking that this particular question should stay on hold.  Its nature is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Here's why:  the main thrust of the question is to seek help getting FlashTool to work properly for you.

Ultimately, that falls outside of the scope of Stack Overflow, as indicated by the close reason in the question - it's not a tool that's directly used for programming.  Yes, it flashes firmware, but you're not writing any code to facilitate that.  Nor is it a tool to assist you in programming anything firmware-related.

I feel like the question is acceptable on Super User.  It's got a brighter future there.

Comment: So should I delete it again from Stackoverflow? Also what would be the tips to increase its development prespective, as I am completely doing it for development purpose (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880972/developer-version-of-android-os), however the fact remains that I am new to Ubuntu enviornment and hence these hurdles but Android app dev is my muse.

Answer (score 1):

You can undelete it yourself, after you edit it into the form you want.  If it looks like a good question then people can vote to reopen it.  It should automatically go into the review reopen queue based on your edit.

Comment: Undelete and then add more detail which has accumulated over the past few days, I have asked more questions related on other sites too so those add up too.